# How to apply multiple conditional filters with group by operation in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have following dataframe named 'data'

[image]

I want to take only those rows where **Actual Discount** value compares with **Discount** value and takes higher sealing value. and if **Actual Discount** is higher that **Discount** as that of **Model** RTD9 it should take highest sealing of Discount.

My final output dataframe should be as followed(coloured yellow in above dataframe),

[image]

Comment: Please do not add pictures of data, it is difficult to work with them. Use `dput()` to share data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `findInterval` to get the closest interval

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Model) %>%
  slice(if(any(Discount > ActualDiscount))  
          which.max(findInterval(Discount, first(ActualDiscount))) else 
          which.max(Discount - ActualDiscount))

#  Model Level Discount ActualDiscount
#  <fct> <int>    <dbl>          <dbl>
#1 BD56      1     21             20  
#2 HT67      2     25             24  
#3 KJ90      3     33             32  
#4 RTD9      3     33.7           35.5
#5 YT61      5     33             32.5
```

Comment: How is the OP helped with code that fails in 1 case? It needs to show the row where the Discount value is the one just higher than the Actual Discount value. And if  the Actual Discount value is always the highest, it needs to show the row with the highest Discount value. It either works, or it doesn't...

Comment: @Sven I am sorry to confuse you maybe I should just remove the second part. The first part is what works 100 % second part is what "almost" works.

Comment: I'm sorry Ronak, that indeed wasn't clear to me, that the first and second part of your answer were independent. My bad, I've given you an upvote. :)

Comment: No problem @Sven :) Glad you atleast commented with the reason :)

Comment: And I'm glad I did, so you could show me I was wrong and I could correct it. :) Your solution is beautiful btw!